# Redundancy in writing type for function

Tags: typescript, types

One of the simplest type for function in TypeScript looks like:

```
let myAdd: (x: number, y: number) => number = function (
  x: number,
  y: number
): number {
  return x + y;
};
```

What is the purpose of redundancy of that? I can not understand it.

Comment: You may annotate variables with their types. You may annotate function arguments and return types with their types. In the above, `myAdd` is an annotated variable whose value is an annotated function. I also don't understand the "purpose" of the redundancy, since you could omit either set of annotations, and the compiler would infer it. Can you explain what your problem is more fully and where you got that code from? If you're asking why it's allowed, it's because those two types of annotations are useful separately. If you're asking something else, please elaborate. Good luck!

Comment: Sure, the source of the code is: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html => "Writing the function type". I just try to write types for more complicated function and decided firstly to look at simple one. I was guessing that it is the simplest version of type, but as answer shown it is not true ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not really the simplest type, I'd even argue that this is a bit overcomplicated. Usually if I create such function, I'll write this:

```
function myAdd(x: number, y: number) {
  return x + y;
}
```

Here the return type is inferred.
If you specifically want to use Function Expression and not function declaration, it's the same:

```
const myAdd = function(x: number, y: number) {
  return x + y;
}
```

Here the return type and `myAdd` variable types will also be inferred. You almost never need to annotate every single thing. In fact, the only thing I usually have to annotate are function parameters unless I write abstract classes or interfaces where everything must be definitely typed. TypeScript is ridiculously good at type inference, so most of types can be harmlessly omitted.

Comment: Quite so. And if you enable `--noImplicitAny` you will always know if you've missed an annotation. A weird thing people seem to do a lot is annotate the parameter types of inline callback functions, which can be very misleading if the inferred type of a param is `any`